# Объединить массивы и вывести в HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, append

есть 2 массива с переменными, нужно их объединить, создать из них элементы *button* с классом *btn-menu*, data элементом *category* (с переменной из массива) и текстом из массива.

```
let category = [Пицца , Роллы , Сеты , Горячие блюда , Салаты , Бизнес-ланч , Супы , Закуски , Десерты , Хлеб , Детское меню , Напитки , Гарниры ];
let slug_id = [pizza, rolls, sets, hot-dish, salads, business-lunch, soups, snacks, desserts, bread, child-menu, drinks, garnishes];
```

Порядок из первого и второго массива соотвествует содержимому, то есть ***Пицца (0)** и **pizza(0)***
Нужно все эти элементы вывести в HTML объект *nav* с классом *container*

Должно получиться горизонтальное меню с кнопками:

```
    <nav class="container">
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="pizza">Пицца </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="rolls">Роллы </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="sets">Сеты </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="hot-dish">Горячие блюда </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="salads">Салаты </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="business-lunch">Бизнес-ланч </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="soups">Супы </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="snacks">Закуски </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="desserts">Десерты </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="bread">Хлеб </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="child-menu">Детское меню </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="drinks">Напитки </button>
        <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="garnishes">Гарниры </button>
    </nav>
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.

Comment: Кавычки в массивах религия не позволяет проставить? И в чём проблема конкретно? Никаких попыток что-то сделать не видно, а готовый результат присутствует.

Answer (score 1):

```
$let_category = ['Пицца', 'Роллы',  'Сеты', 'Горячие блюда', 'Салаты', 'Бизнес-ланч', 'Супы', 'Закуски', 'Десерты', 'Хлеб', 'Детское меню', 'Напитки', 'Гарниры',];
$let_slug_id = ['pizza', 'rolls', 'sets', 'hot-dish', 'salads', 'business-lunch', 'soups', 'snacks', 'desserts', 'bread', 'child-menu', 'drinks', 'garnishes',];

echo count($let_category) . ' ' . count($let_slug_id);

$nav = '<nav class="container">';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($let_category); $i++) {
    $nav .= "<button class=\"btn-menu ripple-btn\" category=\"{$let_slug_id[$i]}\">{$let_category[$i]}</button>" . PHP_EOL;
}

$nav .= '</nav>';


echo $nav;

<nav class="container"><button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="pizza">Пицца</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="rolls">Роллы</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="sets">Сеты</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="hot-dish">Горячие блюда</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="salads">Салаты</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="business-lunch">Бизнес-ланч</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="soups">Супы</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="snacks">Закуски</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="desserts">Десерты</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="bread">Хлеб</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="child-menu">Детское меню</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="drinks">Напитки</button>
    <button class="btn-menu ripple-btn" category="garnishes">Гарниры</button>
</nav>
```

тоже самое и на js и все